# Is there a way to filter by FirstOccurrence/LastOccurrence

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Is there a way to Filter by FirstOccurence and/or LastOccurence Start/End Property of a Series Appointment using ews `SearchFilter` and `FindItems`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the extendedproperties for

First Occurrence PidLidClipStart https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839770.aspx

Last Occurrence (if it has one which it may not) PidLidClipEnd https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765713.aspx

eg

```
  ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidLidClipStart = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Appointment, 0x8235,MapiPropertyType.SystemTime);
  SearchFilter SFilt = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(PidLidClipStart, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Unfortunateley I get a Service Exception : "The property can not be used with this type of restriction."

Comment: ^I Also Tried it with the raw Guid of the Property set, but to no avail